# Reading an Excel Named Range into an Array (VBA)

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

I want to read a named range ('NamedRange') into an array ('NamedRangeAsArray').  I have tried a number of things without success, and am hoping to find a way to do so no matter the length or height of the named range (and by extension then, the dimensions of the array).

I have tried:

```
Dim NamedRangeAsArray As Variant
NamedRangeAsArray = Range("NamedRange").Value
```

(only reads the first cell of the named range into the array [1,1]);

also,

```
NamedRangeAsArray = Range(Workbook.Names("NamedRange").RefersToRange.Address)
```

(does not work at all),

to no avail.  Any ideas?  Please share.  Thanks!

**Update:**

```
Dim NamedRangeAsArray() As Variant
NamedRangeAsArray() = Range(Workbook.Names("NamedRange").RefersToRange.Address)
For i = LBound(NamedRangeAsArray()) To UBound(NamedRangeAsArray())
    MsgBox NamedRangeAsArray(i, 1)
Next i
```

(only reads the first cell of the named range into the array [1,1])

Thank you @findwindow and @Brian for your help.

Comment: Try `Dim NamedRangeAsArray() As Variant`

Comment: As you currently have it `NamedRangeAsArray` is not an array.

Comment: Thank you.  Even with the parenthesis, however, the array contains only the first cell of the named range.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Please update OP to your latest code.

Comment: Try `NamedRangeAsArray = Application.Transpose(Range("NamedRange").Value)`

Comment: Change `NamedRangeAsArray() = Range(Workbook.Names("NamedRange").RefersToRange.Address)` to `NamedRangeAsArray = Range("NamedRange")` Edit: also, since it's more than 1 dimension, try `for each e in NamedRangeAsArray` to loop all dimensions.

Comment: Should be as simple as `NamedRangeAsArray = Range("NamedRange")`, at least I've used this in my applications hundreds of times. And if the range is a table object, and you want headers too, the right side becomes `Range("NamedRange[#All]")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare()

Dim NamedRangeAsArray() As Variant
NamedRangeAsArray = Application.Transpose(Range("NamedRange"))
For i = LBound(NamedRangeAsArray) To UBound(NamedRangeAsArray)
    MsgBox NamedRangeAsArray(i)
Next i

End Sub
```